# Shortest way to find the centralizer and normalizer of $A=\{1,s,r^2,sr^2\}\subseteq D_8$?

Tags: group-theory, alternative-proof, group-actions

$A=\{1,s,r^2,sr^2\}\subseteq D_8$

We know $Z(D_8) = \{ 1,r^2\} \subseteq C_G(A) $ Hence $1,r^2 \in C_G(A) $

also $ sss^{-1} = s, \; s(sr^2)s^{-1} = sr^2 \; $ Hence $s \in C_G(A) $

Since $C_G(A)\leq G,$ using closure $sr^2 \in C_G(A)$

Hence $A\subseteq C_G(A) \Rightarrow |C_G(A)|\geq 4$

By Lagrange $|C_G(A)|=4,8 $. But $rsr^{-1} = sr^2 \neq s$ Hence $r \notin C_G(A)$

$|C_G(A)| \neq 8$. Hence $|C_G(A)|=4 $ and $C_G(A)=A$

We know $C_G(A) \leq N_G(A) \Rightarrow |N_G(A)|\geq 4$. Also  $rsr^{-1}=sr^2 \in N_G(A)$ and $r(sr^2)r^{-1}=s \in N_G(A)$.

Hence $rAr^{-1} = A$. Hence $|N_G(A)|>4 \Rightarrow |N_G(A)|=8 \Rightarrow |N_G(A)|=G$

Is there a better way to solve this?

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. Do you want us to give the shortest way (if there be such) or do you want us to verify whether yours is the shortest?

Comment: @Shaun I just want to know if this would be the best approach to this type of question. Is there a better (shorter) way to solve it?

Comment: Okay. I suggest you [edit] the question to make that clear, then.

Comment: I've edited and added a line in the end.

Answer (score 1):

First show $A$ is a subgroup:

$s$ and $r^2$ are their own inverses. So also is $sr^2$, since it equals $r^2s$ by the group relations.  Thus $A$ is closed and contains an inverse for each element. $\therefore A\le D_8$.

Then $A$ is normal in $D_8$ since $[D_8:A]=2$.

Thus $N_{D_8}(A)=D_8$.

Comment: but we'd have to show $A\leq D_8$ to use that isn't it?

Comment: Index $2$ subgroups are always normal.

Comment: Abhay is correct.  You need first to show that the subset is a subgroup (which it is) in order to apply the index 2 theorem.

Comment: I see.  That hadn't been proven. I've edited.

Comment: Don't think this would be a shorter method then. Proving it as subgroup would be some work in itself, isn't it?

Comment: I'd say so.  But it's a different approach.